# Why classes that comes from spark-libs has precedence before classes from jar in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, jar, dependencies, hadoop-yarn

Let's say we have fat jar with spark application. In other words, it contains all dependencies in jar. However, it is not able to override/hide dependencies provided by spark-libs. I mean that it seems to be strange because classes in jar looks like more near/internal in comparison to "external" classes from spark-libs.

Could anyone explain me how does it work? And what idea is behind such precedence?